# Find limit point of non linear recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, limits, recurrence-relations

Given recurrence relation,

$$a_n = \ln(1+a_{n-1}) , a_n > 0$$

How could we find L such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = L$$

Existence of the limit was not tested.
(Could not think of proper limit to compare...)

I do understand that given recurrence relation has limit point of 0, but multiplying n to such limit hold me back.

Comment: why such limit would exist ?

Comment: What is $a_0$ or $a_1$?

Comment: Currently, only information available was the fact that $a_n > 0$...

Comment: And existance of the limit.... i could not find that also....

Comment: Please edit the question with all the information you were given and what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: It is possible to estimate $L.$ For example ${1\over 2}\log(1+x)\ge {x\over 2}-{x^2\over 4}.$ Let $f(y)=y-{y^2}.$ Then the sequence $a_n$ satisfies ${a_n\over 2}\ge f\left ({a_{n-1}\over 2}\right ).$  Let $b_n$ be defined as $b_1={a_1\over 2}$ and $b_n=f(b_{n-1}).$ Then ${a_n\over 2}\ge b_n.$ I believe that $\liminf nb_n\ge 1.$ Hence $\liminf na_n\ge 2.$

Comment: For convergence, simply applying ratio test on $y_n $ defined as $y_n = n * a_n$ clearly shows it converges, given $a_n$ strictly converges to zero.

Comment: I do not get it. If the limit of $y_n$ exists and is positve,  then $y_{n+1}/y_n$ tends to $1.$ Hence the ratio test is not efficient.  The sequence $a_n$ tends to $0,$ as it is decreasing and positive,  hence convergent to say $a$. The limit  should satisfy $a=\log(1+a),$ i.e. $a=0.$

Answer (score 4):

Clearly
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0. $$
By Stolz's Theorem
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n \\
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\frac{1}{\ln(1+a_{n-1})}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)-n}{\frac{1}{\ln(1+a_{n})}-\frac{1}{\ln(1+a_{n-1})}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+a_{n})\ln(1+a_{n-1})}{\ln(1+a_{n-1})-\ln(1+a_{n})}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\ln(1+a_{n-1}))\ln(1+a_{n-1})}{\ln(1+a_{n-1})-\ln(1+\ln(1+a_{n-1}))}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+\ln(1+x))\ln(1+x)}{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1+\ln(1+x))}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1+\ln(1+x))}\cdot\frac{\ln(1+\ln(1+x))}{\ln(1+x)}\cdot\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)+\frac{x}{1+x}}{\frac1{1+x}-\frac1{1+\ln(1+x)}\frac{1}{1+x}}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)\ln(1+x)+x}{1-\frac1{1+\ln(1+x)}}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)\ln(1+x)+x}{\ln(1+x)}\cdot(1+\ln(1+x))\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\bigg[(1+x)+\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}\bigg]\\
&=&2.
\end{eqnarray}